# How to display a selection made on a list box in another Form in Access

Tags: vb.net, dao

I have create a combobox with a depending  multiselection List box. I also have  a button, wich I wanna asign an event on click. 
I want this event to be able to show the selections the user did (combobox and multi selections on List box) in another Form  to make a little table with more fields and more info.

This is the code i have so far, and trows me an "3265" error.
Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Command129_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("tblConfig Query")

For Each varItem In Me!List126.ItemsSelected
   strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & Me!List126.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "You did not select anything from the list" _
          , vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
   Exit Sub
End If

strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblConfig " & _
         "WHERE tblConfig.TypeConfig IN(" & strCriteria & ");"

         qdf.SQL = strSQL
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "tblConfig Query"
         Set db = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: In which line does the Code throw the error?

Comment: Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("tblConfig Query")

Comment: Try to rename your Query to "tblConfig_Query"

Comment: Still appears the error :(

Comment: Now an Run-time error 3270

Comment: Do you changed the name in Code and DB?

Comment: yes, i did on the query and the code... but still send me an error on this row.:

Comment: DoCmd.OpenQuery "tblConfig_Query"